# Xcode: Array of images fails to instantiate on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got an app that's working perfectly on the simulator, but fails on my iPod Touch (4th gen), and I'd like to know why. The part that's failing is a simple interactive menu that shows six pictures on the root of a `UINavigationController`, then pushes a viewController which instantiates an array of food images, creates a view which holds all the images side-by-side, and moves the viewing area over the image that correlates to the image clicked in the root view. When I run it on the device, the array only instantiates with pointers to two images, and an exception is thrown when the array is used to create the images side-by-side.

```
//code from the pushed view controller
- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {
    // we have 6 images here.
    // we will add all images into a scrollView & set the appropriate size.
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"shrimpquesadilla.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"pulledpork.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"filetMignon.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Reuben.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cajunshrimp.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"primerib.jpg"], nil];
    NSLog(@"stuff: %@", array);
    for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) {
        UIImage *image = [array objectAtIndex:(i-1)];
        UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] 
            initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*scrMain.frame.size.width, 
            0, scrMain.frame.size.width, (scrMain.frame.size.height - 90))];
        imgV.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [imgV setImage:image];
        imgV.tag=i+1;
        [scrMain addSubview:imgV];
    }
    [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrMain.frame.size.width*6, 
         scrMain.frame.size.height)];
    [scrMain scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.count*scrMain.frame.size.width, 
         0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

The output of the NSLog when run through the simulator:

```
2012-08-20 09:51:23.812 DemoTabbed[1545:11603] stuff: (
    "<UIImage: 0x7931150>",
    "<UIImage: 0x6e63270>",
    "<UIImage: 0x6e67700>",
    "<UIImage: 0x6e68040>",
    "<UIImage: 0x6e5c700>",
    "<UIImage: 0x6e64210>"
)
```

And the output when run on the device:

```
2012-08-20 10:26:50.211 DemoTabbed[2128:707] stuff: (
    "<UIImage: 0x197e20>",
    "<UIImage: 0x181270>"
)
```

And then there's the standard error for the index out of bounds. I don't know if it's relevant or not, but two of my icons aren't loading on the device, either, though they work on the simulator. Let me know if you need any more code, or if you have questions about the app or its behavior, I'd be happy to add more.

EDIT: I have tried rearranging the order in which the images are instantiated into the array, and nothing was changed by it. The output stll showed that only two images were pointed to by the array.

Comment: I'd try reordering the images and find out whether the problem is with `filetMignon.jpg` itself (returning `nil` and therefore terminating your list) or the amount of memory consumed by loading these six jpg files at the same time.

Comment: I'd also recommend (a) only loading the images you need to show on the screen at the time; and (b) resize the images for the resolution of your screen.

Comment: Do you have separate targets for iOS and simulator builds ?

Comment: I would try removing the file extensions. Example. `[UIImage imageNamed:@"shrimpquesadilla"]`

Comment: Max, could you elaborate on that? I'm not certain of what you mean.

Comment: And n0oitaf, they vary in size. I haven't re-sized them yet, since the app is still in the test phase.

Comment: Still, how heavy are they .. 1MB, 5MB, 100kb?

Comment: Anywhere from 30kb to 300kb. Most of them are on the low end. Like I said, they're just test images, so I grabbed them off of Google without modifying them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS has a case-sensetive file system. You have a case problem in @"filetMignon.jpg" file, making it resolve to nil image and ending the array elements early.

To fix that, make sure that images are named in same case as you load them (the better idea would be to always have a lowercase image names).

It's not an issue on Simulator, as OS X is using case-insensetive (in 99% cases) filesystem, meaning, @"filetMignon.jpg" and @"filetmignon.jpg" would resolve to same file.

Comment: Isn't it case sensitive in the simulator, too?

Comment: I did have a case inconsistency, but nothing was changed when I adjusted the code to reflect the case-sensitive filename.

Comment: Update: I had TWO case inconsistencies, one right after the other. Once I found and changed the second one, it worked perfectly. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I accidently had lowercase image.png but the files I had were image.PNG which caused the app to fail on the device but work in the simulator.  This was driving me crazy. Thank you for your post :)